# Branding on MySite

Tags: my-site

We have a main site and a mySite. Both are having the same branding with the top navigational bar. This menu contains some URLS linked to main site. I am using a sitemap to generate the relative URLs for this top menu bar. I want to use the same URLs but hardcoded absolute URLs from My Site linked to Main site. I am able to use the same master page as main site for MySite but as links are coded as relative URLs,which results as Broken links. The main reason for this is all the urls in the form of http://mysite.mainsitelist.com. Please let me know how can I get the absolute URLs for the mysite.